# Functions as variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, optimization, functional-programming, memoization

Following is my code of memoization which is working fine, output `"Long Time"` **once** only -

**Code** -

```
function memoAdd80() {
  let cache = {};
  return (n) => {
    if(n in cache) {
      return cache[n];
    }
    console.log('Long Time');
    const answer = n + 80;
    cache[n] = answer;
    return answer; 
  }
}

const memoized80 = memoAdd80();
console.log(memoized80(85)); // Long Time 165
console.log(memoized80(85)); // 165
console.log(memoized80(85)); // 165
```

Though, when writing like this - `memoAdd80()(85)` this caching doesn't works.

```
console.log(memoAdd80()(85)); // Long Time 165
console.log(memoAdd80()(85)); // Long Time 165
console.log(memoAdd80()(85)); // Long Time 165
```

Let me know how can I directly use `memoAdd80` instead of creating a `memoized` variable first and then passing a value to the function.

Comment: _"...this caching doesn't works."_ - It does, but you create three different functions that you then throw away after the first execution

Comment: _"...instead of creating a memoized variable first and then passing a value to the function."_ - But that's the whole reasoning behind memoization o.O

Comment: Each call to `memoAdd80()` creates a new cache. Therefore, it you call it three times, you get three caches. Either you need a *global* cache for all invocations, or you need to stick to the first approach which initialises the cache once. It's not a good idea to try and do "both" since it suggests you've got a design time problem.